# Scrapy rules for links selection

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape vertically pages that are following a simple rule in the html direction:

They have /MLA#### or /MLA-#### (# as random numbers)

The problem is that with the following code scrapy only detects me as good the pages with /MLA-#### name when a /MLA####  or /####MLA### page appears my scrapy code doesn't work and the scraping is wrong

```
 rules =  (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/_Desde_'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/'+'MLA'), follow=True, callback='parse_items'))
```

Previously it was as it follows:

```
 rules =  (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/_Desde_'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/MLA'), follow=True, callback='parse_items'))
```

So how can I say to my code: I want to scrapy all the links that contain MLA no matter what is preceeding or following the words.

Thanks for you comments,
Regards

Answer (score 1):

in fact `'/' + 'MLA'` is totally equal to `'/MLA'` (: it's about string concatenation. What you need is couple of regular expressions.

I think `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d+MLA', r'MLA-\d+'], follow=True, callback='parse_items')` will work for you. Take a read on regular expressions - it's a must for scraping. In this case everything is quite simple: we have MLA and `/d+` which stands for *one or more digits*.

Good luck.